# Link to SonarQube on Jenkins job not available

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

on the main page of a Jenkins job, I see the SonarQube icon, which should be a link, but it's just text:
[image: Jenkins job page with missing link]

I use...

- Jenkins 1.596.2 (also tried 1.609.1)
- Jenkins SonarQube-Plugin 2.1 (also tried 2.2.1)
- Maven 3.3.1
- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6 (when configuring SonarQube post build action)
- sonar runner 2.4 (when configuring SonarQube analysis build step)

After browsing the source code of the jenkins sonarqube-plugin, I found that `SonarUtils.extractSonarProjectURLFromLogs()` seems to be broken. It parses the console output for the regexp "`ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse (.*)`".
My console output never prints this line. It just prints "`ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL`".

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you running? And can you paste your analysis logs (the ones from Jenkins) on pastebin.com and add a link to them please? This is not normal that you only get the "ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL".

Comment: I am running SonarQube 4.1.2.
Unfortunately our enterprise firewall blocks pastebin.com. So I can't paste the full console output.

Comment: First lines of Post Build Action:
[workspace] $ /usr/maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin/mvn -f /home/bldthla1/data/jenkins/jobs/zeus.core.vorschriften-2.0_jvm-reports-plugin/workspace/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@avo11.hhla.de:50017:AVO11 ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://vlxs030:9000/ -Dsonar.branch=rel_2.0 ******** ********

Comment: Last lines:

[INFO] [08:42:55.725] Store results in database
[INFO] [08:42:57.207] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] [08:42:57.209] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
[INFO] [08:42:57.211] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in your logs, you are running the analysis in "preview" mode:

```
... -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview ...
```

As you can read on the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Concepts) about preview mode:

> The source code is analyzed but the measures and issues are not pushed
>   to the SonarQube database. Therefore, they cannot be browsed through
>   the web interface.

So this is normal that you only get a `ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL` message without the related SQ URL (because results are not pushed to the server in preview mode).

Comment: Thank You! I just found the same and was writing an answer, but you were faster :) 
I read somewhere, that not EVERY cont. integration build should upload analysis results into DB. So we only upload to DB nightly. Is there a nice way to see easily, that a Jenkins build failed due to sonar and which alert threshold was hit?

Comment: As you are using an old version of SQ, you can use the Build Breaker plugin for this matter. You can read more on this blog post: http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/.